# Drupal 7 drupal_set_title not working in views

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have the following php code in my view using the Global: PHP field

```
<?php
drupal_set_title($row->title);
?>
```

I have the title field before the php in the order.

I'm sure this used to work but isn't now... any ideas why. I need this in views as I'm getting the title of the content in loading (Based on contextual filters) and I want it to be the page title.

If this is no go... is there another way?

Comment: I needed this for a meta tags module I was building and I found that unless the title was set in a preprocess hook (hook_preprocess_html for example) then it was too late. Hopefully someone else can help but that's what I found when I tried this.

Comment: I take it the view only returns a single result? This method works ok in D6, whether a block or a page view (I just quickly tested). Is there a chance anything else is overriding the title again? It might be an idea (if you have xdebug) to put an `xdebug_get_function_stack()` in `drupal_get_title()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is a bug or not, but I was doing something similar and tried using `drupal_set_title()` in a `hook_preprocess_views_view()`, with no luck. I ended up doing this instead which did work for me.

```
<?php
function my_module_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  // My view
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'my_view') {
    // Code to dynamically set title here...

    // Override view's title, drupal_set_title() was no longer working
    // it didn't work in views Global block either.
    $vars['view']->build_info['title'] = $my_title;
  }
}
?>
```